# Forcing the size of a barplot in R

Tags: r, plot

I plotted this in R using barplot:

[image]

Is there a way, to force the plot to be higher, or each of the "boxes" to be higher?

This is my code:

```
barplot(setNames(rev(c(100,100,...)), rev(names(data))),cex.names=0.6, las=2, horiz=TRUE, width=20)
```

Comment: Change the height of the pane in which the plot is being rendered. In the IDE (RStudio or Rterm), just resize the pane/window. If you are rendering this programmatically (e.g., `shiny` or `rmarkdown`), then you need to specify the figure dimensions.

Comment: I'm using R markdown, where do I specify that?

Comment: [`rmarkdown image size`](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=rmarkdown+image+size) yields https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-size.html. While the website does say `bookdown` (which is a specialization of rmarkdown), it is still applicable. Additionally, there's the SO search [`[r] [knitr] plot size`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+%5Bknitr%5D+plot+size). I'm not including the literal search links with snark, I'm including them to help you pick up which keywords are meaningful in searches (since googling R stuff can be difficult).

Comment: Notably, look for references to `fig.height`, but there are so many other things that can be done with plotting code-chunks and such that knowing where to look for them will help with several other aspects of rmarkdown authorship.